# Rails / MySQL2: Error - Unknown database

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, macos

I'm following a basic tutorial in Linda.
I have been able to install everything properly now, but when I start my Rails server I get this message when I visit `localhost:3000`:

```
Unknown database 'simple_cms_development'
```

and then

```
Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.0ms)
Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (23.5ms)
Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (29.8ms)
```

Comment: @kidkola...run rake db:migrate and check if it works also post your databse.yml file here. There could also be chances that a file may be corrupted...

Answer (score 60):

Have you created the database in MySQL? You should be able to run `rake db:create` and have Rails create it for you.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help! The mysql2 gem was installed but i had obiously not created the database. I run the "rake db:create" suggested by you and it worked perfectly. I had trouble early on with mysql so i think i might have deleted the database when I did a fresh install. Thanks again.

Comment: Not a problem. Don't forget, it's customary to mark the answer that solved your problem as "Accepted" by clicking on the green checkmark outline to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 16):

I had the same error, please run the following command on the Command Prompt:

```
rake db:create
```

to solve the problem.

Comment: plus 1 for being more specific than others

Answer (score 5):

Look for the answers of these questions:

1. Have you installed the mysql2 gem?
2. Is it mentioned in your Gemfile?
3. Did you run the command `rake db:create` ?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes creating database with rake causes issues.

You can also create the database inside mysql

Make sure mysql is in the root %PATH%  in command prompt type echo %PATH% to check.

If it isn't in your PATH.  Then do a quick google search on windows PATH to get instructions

Open command prompt

type mysql -u root -p

type your password that you created for your root

To create database

create database simple_cms_development

done

Answer (score 0):

> was getting the same error but caused was different

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown database 'rdddd_development'
```

/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/mysql2-0.5.2/lib/mysql2/client.rb:90:in `connect'
/Users/commeasure/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/mysql2-0.5.2/lib/mysql2/client.rb:90:in`initialize

faced this error due to the created method dynamically, code is here

```
Role.all.map(&:name).map(&:parameterize).map(&:underscore).each do |name|
    define_method("#{name.to_sym}?") do
     role.name == name.upcase
    end
  end
```

How do I fix this for the temporary purpose just comment it out

Comment: `begin
 Role.all.map(&:name).map(&:parameterize).map(&:underscore).each do |name|
    define_method("#{name.to_sym}?") do
     role.name == name.upcase
    end
  end
rescue  rescue StandardError => e
 e
end
`

This works for me.